# How to setup header for HTTP requests outside of Karate Feature File and not write anything about it in the feature file?

Tags: java, unit-testing, automated-tests, cucumber, karate

While working on a application upon using Karate framework, I need to setup header for authorization before calling any HTTP request on a url. And I don't want to write about header in every Scenario in the feature file. What I want is before running any Scenario I want to setup the header and I don't want to write about it in the feature file.
I have tried and searched for a lot of ways but every solution needs me to write header in the Scenario in the feature file which I don't want.
Can you help we with this?